# What does this syntax mean in string formatting in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting

I saw the syntax below in a tutorial

```
print("{0:>2} in binary is {0:>08b}".format(100))
```

I was wondering what does the greater equal sign (>) does?

and is it necessary to use it?

because when I used it like this

```
print("{0:2} in binary is {0:08b}".format(100))
```

it produced the same result as the first one I mentioned above

Comment: `>` means right-aligned as opposed to `<`, left-aligned. Right-aligned is the default for numbers anyway. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: Better than the official docs in this case https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` means right-aligned as opposed to `<`, left-aligned. Right-aligned is the default for numbers anyway. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec:

> `>`
>
> Forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space (this is the default for numbers).